# Can I set the expires header on all objects in an Amazon S3 bucket all at once?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

I've got about 200k images in a bucket. They all have expires headers of 2050 but I've read you shouldn't send an expires header older than a year. I want to schedule a script to run every month and set the headers to 6 months away. Anything out there? Obviously I'd like to avoid iterating 200k objects.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605501/how-to-set-expires-header-to-all-images-in-a-bucket-in-amazon-s3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I am the developer of this tool, but I think it may answer your question.

[CloudBerry Explore](http://cloudberrylab.com)r freeware will be able to do it in the next release.

Comment: How do you set it, if i may ask? iterate objects?

Comment: Multiselect the objects and set the headers.

Answer (score 2):

S3 doesn't appear to support bulk updates, as its API's contain no such operations.  Some third-party tools claim bulk update capability; however, I wager that they merely automate iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a dumb question. But why set up a script and all that when you can simple add max-age=26297438 ???

max-age=26297438 = about 10 months

Both yslow and g speed accept that an acceptable future date setting