# Where do I set cache information for my images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

This is about a `Rails` app on `Heroku` that runs behind `CloudFront` and serves `ActiveStorage` images from the `Bucketeer` add-on.

Cache config in both the `Rails` app itself and `CloudFront` are right on target for `css`, `js`, and even key, important requests (like search results, 3rd party info fetched from APIs, etc).

What I can't figure out how to cache are the images that come from the `Bucketeer` add-on.

Right now the images seem to come from the `Bucketeer` bucket every time. They show up with no Cache TTL.

I'd like for them to be cached for up to a year both at the CloudFront level and the visitor's browser level.

Is this possible?

It seems like the `Bucketeer` add-on itself gives us no control over how the bucket and/or the service handles caching.

Where can I force these files to show up with caching instructions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your findings here

Additionally, I found that `S3Service` accepts upload options
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb#L12

So you can add the following code to your `storage.yml`

```
s3:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: ID
  secret_access_key: KEY
  region: REGION
  bucket: BUCKET
  upload:
    cache_control: 'public, max-age=31536000'
```

For a full list of available options refer to AWS SDK

Comment: This did not work for me. My uploads are through `rails_admin`. Could that be related?

Comment: @vivipoit
You should check which ActiveStorage service your uploads use underneath.
In the `storage.yml` there should be a line `service: S3` (see updated answer for full content)

If it's not S3 you should check what options the desired ActiveStorage service accepts.

List of services can be found here https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/6-0-stable/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service

Gems may provide custom services under the same namespace

Comment: Even though I said it hadn't worked, I left it there and it DOES work. I guess I must have checked the wrong files. Sorry about that. This was helpful and has been great.

Comment: I'm now looking forward to the possibility of serving Active Storage files through CDN, which would be awesome on infinite levels and seems to be ready for Rails 6.1!! :-) So many performance problems will go away when that becomes a reality. :-)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching, I learned that `Bucketeer` does give bucket control. You just have to use `AWS CLI`.

Here is the link to `AWS` docs on `CLI`:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html

And here is the link where `Bucketeer` tells you how to get started with that on their service:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bucketeer#using-with-the-aws-cli

This means you can install `AWS CLI`, do the `aws configure` with the credentials `Bucketeer` provides, and then go on to change `cache-control` in the bucket directly.

`AWS` does not seem to have a feature for setting `cache-control` defaults for an entire bucket or folder, so you actually do it to each object.

In my case, all of my files/objects in the bucket are images that I display on the website and need to cache, so it's safe to run a command that does it all at once.

Such a command can be found in this answer:
[How to set expires headers to all images in a bucket in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605501/how-to-set-expires-headers-to-all-images-in-a-bucket-in-amazon-s3#answer-30225271)

For me, it looked like this:
`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name s3://my-bucket-name --recursive  --acl public-read  --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age=43200000`

The command basically copies the entire bucket onto itself while adding the `cache-control max-age=43200000` header to each object in the process.

This works for all existing files, but will not change anything for future changes or additions. You'd have to run this again every so often to catch new stuff and/or write code to set your object headers when saving the object to the bucket. Apparently there are people that have had luck with this. Not me.

Thankfully, I found this post:
https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/caching-variants-with-activestorage

This monkey-patch basically changes `ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show` to use `Rails` action caching for variants. Take a look. If you're having similar issues, it's worth the read.

There are drawbacks. For my case, they were not a problem, so this is the solution I went with.